# The value of $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty } \left(\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{\sin \left(\frac{x}{2 i-1}\right)}{\frac{x}{2 i-1}}\right) \, \mathbb{d}x$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I came across this problem on Facebook the other day, so probably you guys have already seen it.

Define the following integral:
$$I(n):=\int_0^{\infty } \left(\prod _{i=1}^n \frac{\sin \left(\frac{x}{2 i-1}\right)}{\frac{x}{2 i-1}}\right) \, \mathbb{d}x$$

Using Mathematica, I found the symbolic solutions are:

$$I(1)=I(2)=\dots=I(7)=\frac\pi2$$

However,

$$I(8)=\frac{467807924713440738696537864469 }{935615849440640907310521750000}\pi\approx0.499999999993\pi$$
$$I(9)=\frac{17708695183056190642497315530628422295569865119}{35417390788301195294898352987527510935040000000}\pi\approx0.499999994\pi$$

I didn't go further. My question is, should $I(n)=\frac\pi2$ for all positive integers $n$, and the above results are just some roundoff errors in symbolic calculation?

---

**Edit 5 Nov 2022**

3Blue1Brown offers an incredible explaination in [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=851U557j6HE). It is much easier to see the reason with Fourier transform!

Comment: I think this has appeared in some question on unexpected results or something like that. I can't find the link now, though. It is a funny property, but not so strange after it is explained.

Comment: It's explained here: http://mathoverflow.net/a/11607/4678

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BorweinIntegrals.html

Comment: See also [Borwein integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein_integral).